# Uploading Files to S3 in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I have a a school project and I thought everything was going well then I deployed it and found out users can't upload images onto heroku due to its ephemeral filesystem. My whole app pretty much centers around users uploading images.

I read somewhere to work through AWS S3 storage. So I was following the instructions at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3.

I've gone through most of the configuration process but at the end it says:

Put the following into a file named `index.php`

```
<?php
require('vendor/autoload.php');
// this will simply read AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY from env vars
$s3 = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory();
$bucket = getenv('S3_BUCKET')?: die('No "S3_BUCKET" config var in found in env!');
?>
<html>
    <head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
    <body>
        <h1>S3 upload example</h1>
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_FILES['userfile']) && $_FILES['userfile']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
    // FIXME: add more validation, e.g. using ext/fileinfo
    try {
        // FIXME: do not use 'name' for upload (that's the original filename from the user's computer)
        $upload = $s3->upload($bucket, $_FILES['userfile']['name'], fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'rb'), 'public-read');
?>
        <p>Upload <a href="<?=htmlspecialchars($upload->get('ObjectURL'))?>">successful</a> :)</p>
<?php } catch(Exception $e) { ?>
        <p>Upload error :(</p>
<?php } } ?>
        <h2>Upload a file</h2>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
            <input name="userfile" type="file"><input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Two Questions:

It does not say where to put `index.php`. I assume it goes in the project root directory.

My other question is in the code itself. On line 15 they say `do not use 'name' for upload (that's the original filename from the user's computer)` I'm not sure what that means, how do I know what the file name of the user's upload will be?

Comment: You wouldn't put this in `index.php` in an existing application.  It's a standalone example/demo app.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can place index.php in project root folder or another folder with core files (autoload in your case).
2) name - it's file name. As ex:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<input type="file" name="myfile">
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

In this case you should use `['myfile']['name']`.
If you need to modify filename (or use unique name), you can add something like `time().'_'.$_FILES['userfile']['name']`.

If filename equal `$_FILES['userfile']['name']`, the file will be saved with same name, which you have uploaded. As example, if you upload file.txt, but  file with same name already exists on S3, it will be replace. Maybe they describe this issue. It's possible to use dynamic filenames.